# Div tags with merged rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve what is shown in the below picture. 
Found a few links online, where people have suggested to use table-cell. Tried it, but not getting the exact result. Are there any better standard ways to achieve this ? Please suggest.

Tried code:

CSS

```
.left, .right{
    display:table-cell;
```

HTML

```
<div class=left>
   <div> Cell A text ... </div>
   <div> Cell B text ... </div>
</div>
<div class=right>
   <div> Cell C text ... </div>
</div>
```

[image: Cell structure]

Comment: `display:table-cell` can't merge two columns.

Comment: Can you not achieve this with floats? http://jsfiddle.net/89HWP/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do:

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdYm5/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='table'>
            <div class='cell'>Cell A</div>
        </div>
        <div class='table'>
            <div class='cell'>Cell B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>Cell C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I can't get the text to align vertically in the center here.

Answer (score 0):

Add right column `vertical-align: middle;` property to your existing solution. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JMq88/3/)